# How to send the value of select tag using ajax to php residing on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Problem**

I want to use the `select` tag to select a value and send the value using ajax call to a PHP embedded in the same page.

Here, in my code, I am using the select tag and as soon as I select any value from the drop-down, the value is being sent to the javascript and being alerted properly. But when I **$_POST['option']** in PHP and echo it, it is not getting printed on the page.

I know PHP is a server-side language and anything written in PHP executes first when a page is loaded.

**tablesize.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0 /jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function fetch_select(val){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'tablesize.php',
                datatype:'json',
                data: {option:val},
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(val);
                    //document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="heading">Dynamic Select Option Menu Using Ajax and PHP</p>
        <center>
        <div id="select_box">
            <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
                <option value="10">state</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['option'])){
        $val=$_POST['option'];
        echo $val;
    }
?>
```

Thanks...

Comment: your php needs to be on a different page for ajax to work. Thats why you have the `url` parameter in ajax. In the success function of ajax request you can then update any part of the page with the response from php

Comment: In your ajax settings, you can use, in data:  `$('#form').serialize()` . Enclose your select tag inside a form that has `id="form"` before you continue, so `serialize()` will work.

Comment: Your code working fine for me if I remove extra space from `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0 /jquery.min.js"` (near to 2.2.0)

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale Okay.. thanks for that.. But even when i am changing the url to a different page say "ajax.php", i am still not getting the value of "option" printed using echo.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes i did.. sorry i am still figuring out how to reply on stackoverflow. Well, to let you know, there is no space after 2.2.0 in my source code. I am sorry if it got here by mistake. But that doesnt seems to be the cause of error.

Comment: @KarloKokkak Can you please attach a snippet of the same with explainataion? Thanks

Comment: @KrishnaSharma posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution

The **ajax success** contains your result. The error is in your printing method.

You need a different file for ajax here I use **ajax.php**.

One more thing put scripts at last on HTML page always.

**tablesize.php**

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="heading">Dynamic Select Option Menu Using Ajax and PHP</p>
        <center></center>
        <div id="select_box">
            <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
                <option value="10">state</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <p id="print-ajax"></p><!--Result will print here-->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0 /jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function fetch_select(val){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    datatype:'json',
                    data: {option:val},
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#print-ajax').html(response);//This will print you result
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
echo $_POST['option'];die;
```

Answer (score 1):

**same page ajax calling and echo value**

```
<?php
        session_start();
        ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(document).on("change","#sel",function(){
                        var val = $(this).val();
                        console.log(val);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: 'index.php?action=data',
                            datatype:'json',
                            data: {"option":val},
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert(val);
                                location.href="index.php";

                            }
                        });
                    });

                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="select_box">
                <select id="sel" name="sel">
                    <option <?php if($_SESSION['val']=="a") echo "selected" ;?> value="a">a</option>
                    <option <?php if($_SESSION['val']=="b") echo "selected" ;?> value="b">b</option>
                    <option <?php if($_SESSION['val']=="c") echo "selected" ;?> value="c">c</option>
                    <option <?php if($_SESSION['val']=="d") echo "selected" ;?> value="d">d</option>
                    <option <?php if($_SESSION['val']=="e") echo "selected" ;?> value="e">e</option>
                    <option <?php if($_SESSION['val']=="e") echo "selected" ;?> value="f">f</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
        $val = $_POST['option'];
        if($_REQUEST['action']=="data"){
            $_SESSION['val']=$val;
            echo "Selected value = ".$_SESSION['val'];
        }elseif ($val=="") {
            echo "Selected value = ".$_SESSION['val'];
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Different ajax.php
and write code here and url change in your ajax code.

Ajax.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['option']))
{
   $val=$_POST['option'];
   echo $val;  
}
?>
```

Your ajax code...

```
function fetch_select(val){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            datatype:'json',
            data: {option:val},
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                //document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response; 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I did that but still even after echoing in php, it is not printing the value of 'option' being selected in the page

Comment: @KrishnaSharma I have given 2 solutions:- with ajax and without ajax. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the wrong variable on ajax post success. You needed `response` variable to alert of PHP script's output.

Also put the PHP post handler block to the top of the page so that HTML contents will not be included in the response for AJAX.

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['option'])){
        $val=$_POST['option'];
        echo $val; exit;
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function fetch_select (val){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'tablesize.php',
                datatype:'json',
                data: { option:val },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="heading">Dynamic Select Option Menu Using Ajax and PHP</p>
        <center>
        <div id="select_box">
            <select onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
                <option value="10">state</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```